How to prove $|x+y|^q+|x-y|^q \le 2(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{q/p},p\in (1,2),pq=p+q$

How to prove $|x+y|^q+|x-y|^q \le 2(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{q/p},p\in (1,2),pq=p+q$

This inequality looks like a generalization of the Minkowski inequality. I have tried two methods: one is to break it down and apply scaling separately, which obviously doesn't work; the other is to attempt using the auxiliary inequality $( s^q + t^q \leq (s^2 + t^2)^{q/2} )$,                      but that also failed.
This problem is still different from the inequality below, $2(|a|^p + |b|^p) \leq |a + b|^p + |a - b|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p + |b|^p)$,as the original inequality involves powers of $p $ and $q$.. I appreciate the answer below for pointing out the origin of the inequality. The two cases of Clarkson's inequalities on Wikipedia happen to correspond exactly to these two problems.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

If you know about the complex interpolation, the following proof will work. In fact, this proof is a standard way to prove Clarkson's inequality, which is an $L^p$-generalization of this inequality.
The inequality is equivalent to
$$\left[\left|\frac{x+y}{2}\right|^q+\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|^q \right]^{1/q}\leq\left[\frac{|x|^p+|y|^p}{2} \right]^{1/p} \tag{1}$$
for $1<p<2$. So let us begin by first proving this inequality for the extremal cases $(p,q)=(1,\infty)$ and $(2,2)$. The first case follows from the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\frac{x\pm y}{2}\right|\leq \frac{|x|+|y|}{2}, $$
and the second case is just the parallelogram law. Now the general case will follow by interpolating these two results. Define
$$ T(x,y)=\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x-y}{2} \right)\qquad (x,y\in\mathbb{C}). $$
Then the above estimates say that $T: \ell^q(\{1,2\})\to\ell^p_\nu\{(1,2)\}$ is bounded for $p=1$ and $p=2$ with operator norm $1$; here, $\ell^p_\nu$ denotes the $\ell^p$ space equipped with the measure $\nu(\{1\})=\nu(\{2\})=1/2$. It follows from the complex interpolation that $T:\ell^q(\{1,2\})\to\ell^p_\nu\{(1,2)\}$ is bounded and has norm $1$ for every $1\leq p\leq 2$, which proves the assertion.
By the way, since we are dealing with finite sequence spaces $\ell^p(\{1,2\})$, I think that there might be an elementary interpolation argument which avoids using the Riesz-Thorin theorem, but I'm not sure. (A direct application of M. Riesz's convexity theorem would work, of course, but it seems no big different to appealing to Riesz-Thorin.)
